# How to send a message with an automatically thrown exception?

Tags: java, exception, message, throw, throwable

When manually throwing an exception, you can send a small message:

```
throw new Exception("this message");
```

but when running this code, I have to input a float, so if I enter a string for example, the code itself throws an exception but how do I send a same sort of message?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan;
        float feeHold;

        System.out.println("\nEnter Registration Fee (only numbers)");

        try {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            feeHold = scan.nextFloat();

            System.out.println("\n" + feeHold);
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Put a `System.out.println` statement in your `catch` block.

Comment: @VGR That's just a regular print statement though. Below answers suggest to throw a new exception in catch which works in a way

Comment: If you didn’t create the exception, you can’t alter its message.  At best, you can create a new exception with a message of your own choosing, and make a caught exception the cause of your new exception.  But your question says “automatically thrown exception” so I don’t know if that satisfies your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Directly you can do this by wrapping your exceptionable code into new `try-catch` block and throwing new custom exception from `catch`, but this code smells really really bad, moreover, you shouldn't do this cause the library/sdk vendor wants to throw exact exception. But if you want to print your own message you can to it by simply call `System.out.println("your own message")` in catch clause.

Comment: Yeah I could just leave it as is or print something, I was just wondering if it was possible to do something like that. This is just an assignment so I don't have to worry about the performance and efficiency of the code so just experimenting different ways and try to find my way out if problems occur. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could catch the `InputMismatchException`, as you're doing correctly, but instead of calling `e.printStackTrace()`, you could throw a new Exception with your custom message. Keep in mind that you'd also need to declare that your `main` may throw an Exception.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner scan;
        float feeHold;

        System.out.println("\nEnter Registration Fee (only numbers)");

        try {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            feeHold = scan.nextFloat();

            System.out.println("\n" + feeHold);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            throw new Exception("Here's your custom message");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Registration Fee (only numbers)
abc
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Here's your custom message
at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

This is just a way to do what you asked, probably not the most suitable.
Look a bit into the [Exception documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and you'll surely find a more structured and elegant way to accomplish your task.

Comment: This works, the other "at" lines that explain the exception disappear though. None of this is compulsory, I'm just brainstorming as much as I can. Yeah, there may be better methods but this works for now for the assignment I'm making. Thank you

Comment: @PardeepKumar Yes, because I dropped the `e.printStackTrace()` call in order to focus on outputting only a custom message. In the `catch` block you have access to (InputMismatch)Exception `e`, so you can also output all kind of information about what you caught. Of course, it has to be done **before** throwing the new Exception, or in a further `try-catch` block, but again, not the cleanest of codes I would say.